# In C - While Loop Exit issue during usage of strtok

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop, strtok

I tried using strtok to split a string and store individual words in a 2D array.I have put printf statements and checked whether individual words are getting stored or not and saw that words are getting stored.
But the problem is while loop does not terminate at all, while executing it does not print exit statement "Hi".
I am unable to find the mistake here.
Can someone help me with this?

```
int wordBreak(char* str, char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH])
{
    int x=0;
    const char  *delimiters = " :,;\n";
    char* token = strtok(str,delimiters);
    strcpy(words[x],token);
    x++;
    while(token!=NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL,delimiters);
        strcpy(words[x],token);
        x++;
    }
    printf("Hi\n");
    return x;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `char* token = strtok(str,delimiters);` returns `NULL`? You have a few things out of order. Remove the first `strcpy(words[x],token);` and `x++;` and move `token = strtok(NULL,delimiters);` to the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks David C. Rankin. I made the changes u specified and code is running well now...

Comment: You are welcome -- remember in programming, and especially in C, you need to validate every value or input that is critical to the continued operation of your program. The man-page for each function provides concise information on the proper use, return and error conditions you should check (they are a bit cryptic at first -- but you will come to appreciate how concise and well they are actually written) Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must always ensure the return of `strtok` is not `NULL` before calling `strcpy` to copy to your array. A simple rearrangement will ensure that is the case:

```
int wordBreak (char* str, char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH])
{
    int x = 0;
    const char *delimiters = " :,;\n";
    char *token = strtok (str,delimiters);
    
    while (x < MAX_WORDS && token != NULL) {
        if (strlen (token) < MAX_WORD_LENGTH) {
            strcpy (words[x++], token);
            token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);
        }
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: token '%s' exeeded MAX_WORD_LENGTH - skipped\n",
                     token);
    }
    
    return x;
}
```

You also must ensure `x < MAX_WORDS` by adding the additional condition as shown above and a test to ensure `strlen(token) < MAX_WORD_LENGTH` before copying to your array.